# Jmeter testing for Login

Tags: testing, authentication, jmeter, performance-testing

I have to test a web-app for login using Jmeter.

How is that done?

Should I give the path of the login page in the HTTP Request sampler and add the username and password to  the login config element?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It needs to be realistic hence your test should be designed as follows:

1. HTTP GET Request (simulate opening Login page with a browser)

   - [Post Processor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#postprocessors) to fetch dynamic parameters values (if any)
2. HTTP POST Request (login event itself) where you pass your credentials and dynamic parameters

   - (optional) [Response Assertion](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Response_Assertion) to verify that user is really logged i

I would also recommend adding [HTTP Cookie Manager](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Cookie_Manager) to represent browser cookies and deal with cookie-based authentication.

See [How To Use JMeter For Login Authentication](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/207421705-How-to-use-JMeter-for-Login-Authentication) guide for step-by-step overview and demo