# missing authentication or invalid log in

Tags: api, authentication, http-headers, jmeter, blazemeter

I am new to Jmeter. Trying to use this tool for load/performance testing.

steps:

- go to library.xxx.com
- log in
- logout

the application I am trying allows a user to log in with username/password. In the background however, if the user has correct credentials s/he is issued with bearer token. This token is valid until user logs out. this bearer token is generated against the validation of user's credentials.

The issue I am facing using Jmeter is how to keep this token throughout the test, that is make it dynamic.

Here is call sequence -

[image]

Now when I use blazemeter's chrome extension to record the test and load it in the Jmeter- here is how it gets loaded

[![enter image description here][2]][2]

When auth.onecl....com makes a Post request for the first time, it passes.

However when it makes another call it fails because the bearer token is invalid. The only difference when I compared the Request headers of the call sequence is

missing "Authorization: bearer 5a010a8f995d2" in the second.

I used regular expression extractor, BeanShell Processor, etc. but nothing works.

Here is what I tried so far-

[Jmeter testing for Login](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37852721/jmeter-testing-for-login)

[JMeter Basic Authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12560494/jmeter-basic-authentication)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OhDPx.png)

Answer (score 0):

This `Authorization: bearer xxxxx` indicates that your application is protected with [OAuth 2.0](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6750) therefore you have 2 options (depending on your application design):

- If this OAuth token is permanent - just obtain all of them using sniffer tool and put into CSV file along with users credentials
- If the token has limited lifetime - it can still be correlated, check out [How to Run Performance Tests on OAuth Secured Apps with JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-run-performance-tests-oauth-secured-apps-jmeter) article for more details on bypassing OAuth challenges in JMeter tests

Comment: Thanks Dimitri. Here it is outlined more properly, I cannot even find a way to  store token as variable as here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24542747/jmeter-alter-http-headers-during-test?answertab=oldest#tab-top

Comment: I resolved this on my own. I had to capture the passKey using Json Extractor and then use RegEx extractor to get bearer token. NO programming was required